# React Hooks (useState) and Mobx [No mobx-react-lite]

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, react-hooks, react-tsx

in my react application (with typescript) I want to use React hooks (specifically useState) to manage the form state and meanwhile use it as an observable component for Mobx store but I get the error

> Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

so for instance in the following component

```
import * as React from "react";
import { inject, observer } from "mobx-react";
import { MyStore } from "./MyStore";

interface IProps {
  myStore?: MyStore;
  id: string;
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<IProps> = props => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.id}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default inject("myStore")(observer(MyComponent));
```

I saw a solution but that was using `React.createContext` for exporting the store class. is not where the old approach for Mobx and Hooks?

here is the [sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/5vzv8n9y0x) for the example

Comment: `mobx-react@5` does not support hooks, but [version 6 will support it, which is in `rc.4` right now](https://codesandbox.io/s/zk7555yz0l).

Comment: @Tholle, Thanks. BTW as I see you are so active here especially for react tag, do you think as using context became much easier since 16.8, is it more convenient to build custom state manager for small to mid-size apps, rather than importing some MB of library?

Comment: You could definitely use e.g. the [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook and share the state object and the dispatch function through context, which will be suitable for a lot of use cases, but I don't think it will replace MobX for mid-sized apps. It depends a lot on your particular project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @Tholle mentioning the Mobx version, now that the [Mobx 6](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#choosing-your-version) is released this question is solved

Answer (score 6):

`mobx-react` doesn't support hooks and if you wish to use hooks with mobx you need to make use of [`mobx-react-lite`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react) which is also mentioned in the [github documentation](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react)

To do that you can make use of `React.createContext` instead of provider and `useContext` instead of `inject`

**Index.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import MyComponent, { Store } from "./MyComponent";

import "./styles.css";
import MyStore from "./MyStore";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <Store.Provider value={MyStore}>
      <div className="App">
        <MyComponent id={"someID"} />
      </div>
    </Store.Provider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**MyComponent.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { MyStore } from "./MyStore";

interface IProps {
  myStore?: MyStore;
  id: string;
}

export const Store = React.createContext();
const MyComponent: React.FC<IProps> = props => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState("");
  const store = React.useContext(Store);
  console.log(state, store);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.id}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default MyComponent;
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wnmm568107)